# Custom error message on session timeout in flask

Tags: python, flask

I have implemented flask's sessions in my flask application. The current behaviour of the application is that after the session timeout every request has a response of 403 forbidden:

> 403 Forbidden
>
> ### Forbidden
>
> You don't have
> the permission to access the requested resource. It is either
> read-protected or not readable by     the server.

I do not want this. I want to return a custom error message whenever the session times out. I have implemented an error handler, but I have no way of differentiating the 403 after session timeouts from other 403s in the application (I cannot check if session exists because some specific calls in the application don't require a session and It may result in the bypassing of some errors).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use errorhandler to display a custom 403 HTML page.

```
from flask import abort

@app.route('/')
def home():
    if not session.get('user'):
        abort(403) # this will invoke the below given error handler
    else:
        # something else

@app.errorhandler(403)
def page_not_found(error):
    return render_template('403.html'), 403
```

Comment: When the session is timed out flask does not go into my code, so this won't work I'm afraid (Even if it did, it would do no good as there are calls in which the application is not using session and. the actual result would be masked).

Comment: share you code also